# Wordpress widget - how to pass arguments to constructor

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

As the title suggests, how can I pass arguments to a widget constructor?  By looking at the source code, it appears that register_widget() only takes a class name.

I've seen a few references to wp_register_widget_control(). Is this something I should consider? If so, I would appreciate if someone could give me a short code example on how to use it to pass arguments.